# How to find out what first day of week is? (Monday or Sunday)

Tags: ios, nscalendar

I want to check if the first day of the week for a user is Monday or Sunday to perform some actions with the calendar. Is it possible to determinate that using `NSCalendar` or any other way?

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://gist.github.com/dgyesbreghs/5e1ddbfb3e85643ba706

Comment: @aBilal17 as I can see it gives a NSDate instance of a first day of the week (but you need to set it manually, Monday or Sunday). The NSDate does not tell is it a monday or sunday...

Comment: "*Is it possible to determinate that using NSCalendar?*" - any reason you didn't look at the reference documentation for `NSCalendar/Calendar` before posting your question?

Comment: @maddy thanks, for some reason I overlook that property...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just:

**Swift**:

```
Calendar.current.firstWeekday
```

**Obj-C:**

```
[NSCalendar currentCalendar].firstWeekday
```

With 1 = Sunday.

Comment: Hm, this won't work correctly if you went into Preferences → Calendar and changes the "start week on" setting.

Comment: Yeah of course, this is the expected behavior.

Comment: So how would one get the start of the week configured in settings ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `firstWeekday` property…

```
var calendar = Calendar.current

calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
print("\(calendar.locale!) starts on day \(calendar.firstWeekday)")
// en_GB starts on day 2

calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
print("\(calendar.locale!) starts on day \(calendar.firstWeekday)")
// en_US starts on day 1
```

---

*update*

Per @maddy's comment below, `Calendar.current` will have the correct `locale` set for the current user.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
print("\(calendar.locale!) starts on day \(calendar.firstWeekday)")
// en_GB starts on day 2 (in my case)
```

Comment: You should make it clear that if you want to know the current user's first day of the week, you do not need to doing anything with the locale.